# android cliprect with negative values does not change parent view rect

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a child view and I want the canvas that to draw a circle that has "pixels" in the negative side of the axis

```
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 50f, paint);
```

In order to do that i use clipRect, this works fine and i see the full cirlce.
However when I use requestLayout on the parent view and changes the x,y postion of the child view
the negative sids of the circle are not shown
please advise me what to do

here is the code:

```
    package natan.android.TestCanvas;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

    public class TestCanvasActivity extends Activity {

        View childView;
        RelativeLayout parentView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            childView = new View(this)
            {

                @Override
                protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                    canvas.clipRect(-50, -50, 50, 50,android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 50f, paint);
                    super.onDraw(canvas);
                }

            };

            parentView = new RelativeLayout(this);
            parentView.addView(childView);
            LayoutParams layoutParms = (LayoutParams)(childView.getLayoutParams());
            layoutParms.leftMargin=150;
            layoutParms.topMargin=150;
            setContentView(parentView);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            LayoutParams layoutParms = (LayoutParams)(childView.getLayoutParams());
            layoutParms.leftMargin=100;
            layoutParms.topMargin=100;
            parentView.requestLayout();
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured out a soulation
I took it from here

http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java.shtml

using this line of codes fixed the problem

```
   parentView.setClipChildren(false);
```

and

```
   parentView.requestLayout();
   parentView.invalidate();
```

Hopes this helps someone else and If someone has more insight on this problem please add it

here is the full code:

```
    public class TestCanvasActivity extends Activity {

        View childView;
        RelativeLayout parentView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            childView = new View(this)
            {

                @Override
                protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 50f, paint);
                    super.onDraw(canvas);
                }

            };






            parentView = new RelativeLayout(this)
            {

                @Override
                protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t,
                        int r, int b) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
                }

            };
            parentView.setClipChildren(false);

            parentView.addView(childView);
            parentView.setClipChildren(false);
            LayoutParams layoutParms = (LayoutParams)(childView.getLayoutParams());
            layoutParms.leftMargin=150;
            layoutParms.topMargin=150;

            setContentView(parentView);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            LayoutParams layoutParms = (LayoutParams)(childView.getLayoutParams());
            layoutParms.leftMargin=100;
            layoutParms.topMargin=100;

            parentView.requestLayout();
            parentView.invalidate();

            return super.onTouchEvent(event);


        }


    }
```